# Drawing a signature and storing it in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to have the option in my app to make a signature drawing with the finger and saving this signature. The first part is solved thanks to https://github.com/edwardinubuntu/Painter. My doubt is how to store and retrieve this signature. The easiest way, for me, would be to save the squiggles and points arrays archiving. But I don't know if with several hundreds of signatures performance may be affected.

Don't I have to worry about? Should I use sqlite? Should I store the signature as an image? With the last option maybe would be difficult to modify a saved signature...

Any comments will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should have an array of CGPoint. You can store it in `NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults`.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:YOUR_ARRAY_OF_CGPOINTS forKey:@"MY_SIG"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Retrieving the array is also easy.

```
NSArray *arr_sig = [defaults objectForKey:@"MY_SIG"];
```

Comment: Thanks Shivan! I need to store several signatures, maybe several hundreds. So, I think I can not use your solution.

Comment: You can still use it. Just use a different "key" to store it.

Comment: for storing multiple hundreds of signatures, userdefaults is not an optimized solution.

Comment: Any reference link saying so? Of course it's better to manage it using database like SQLite, but the complexity will be a lot higher.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small function on the MainView.m that generates the image:

```
- (UIImage *) getImage
{
    CGSize bounds = self.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds);
    CALayer *layer = [self.layer presentationLayer];
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution :**

- Easy and maintainable way to save and retreive signature in iOS, works for all ios versions.
  I am sorry for not adding answer here. I am giving link. I am trying to post optimized code here ASAP.
- [Find here](https://github.com/jcmontiel/SignatureView)

Thanks